# Do computers contain more information than the information stored in them?

Tags: thermodynamics, information, computer

Computers carry information like graphical, mathematical, musical information, etc. Nevertheless, it seems to me that a computer contains much more information than the kinds of information I described. A logical gate can have one bit as output, but the gate itself contains much more (useless) data in the form of the particles that make up the gate (if the size of the gates is getting smaller, the difference of both kinds of data is getting less). So does a computer as a whole contains more information than the information that's useful for us?

Comment: "*but the gate itself contains much more data*" What do you mean with much more data?

Comment: If by *"but the gate itself contains much more data,"* what you mean is that all the atoms in the gate contain a lot of information, isn't that irrelevant? We can't make perfectly efficient computing devices, and will never be able to.

Comment: "Data" and "information" are not the same thing. A lot of data can carry little information and vice versa. I can use a million pixels to show you the word "hello" or I can give you five ascii characters - same information, different data. Not sure if that is what you are after - as written your question doesn't seem to be about physics...

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. The last sentence should be clarified, but the meaning of the post is clear enough.

Comment: @Floris Well, my question is actually the physical storage of data. It's stored on media that are constructed out of very much elementary particles. The information contained in these elementary particles seems to me much more than the information or stored on devices made up by elementary particles. Is it that only in the limit of each elementary particle can carry one bit, both kinds of information become the same?

Comment: I see. Are you asking about the relationship between practical storage capacity, and theoretical storage capacity? That's a very big field... indeed, in principle "one quantum state" could equal "one bit of information" - but in reality you need to use many atoms to create a single state that you can reliably interrogate / set. As technology evolves, memory units get smaller... fewer atoms per bit needed. Does that address your question?

Comment: @Floris Thanks, Floris. Yes, this was what I more or less meant, of which I already thought that this "mechanism" was at work. But to be sure I asked the question.

Comment: If you edit your question to clarify that, I would vote to re-open it .

Comment: @Floris I'll surely do that, but here in Holland it's already late and my  girlfriend is pulling on me with her eyes, so...

Comment: *It's stored on media that are constructed out of very much elementary particles.* Not really, they're made of silicon, copper, etc. (i.e., atoms).

Comment: @KyleKanos But the atoms are composed of nucleons (and electrons), which in turn are composed of quarks, but quarks can't be used to store information. Nucleons in turn cán be used to store information.

Comment: Yes, they consist of quarks, but they are **not** quarks. Much like you are made of atoms, but you are not an atom.

Answer (score 2):

> Computers carry information like graphics data, mathematical data, musical data, etc.

Data is stored in various types of memory.  But it's just sets of bits until some interpretation is placed on that data.  It's not even sets of bits unless I know how to use the device properly.

If an alien hands me it's version of a hard disk full of valuable technological advances but then just races back to it's space craft and leaves without explaining how to read the data it's just useless.  I'd have no idea about how to read the data, how the data was stored in the device, how not to break it (!), the language used, the standardized formats used, the intended use of those formats and so on.  The full context of the data is very important.

> Nevertheless, the data stored in the computer as a physical object is much greater than the kinds of data I described.

No it's not.  It's just data.  Remember our alien !

It's the context that you are omitting.  The information on how to interpret the data.

> A logical gate can have one, two or more bits as output, but the gate itself contains much more data (but if the size of the gates is getting smaller, the difference of both kinds of data is getting less).

No.  It is designed to store one bit.  That's all.

> Is it the usefulness of the data stored in the memory of a computer that makes the difference ?

It is the implicit knowledge of how to interpret the data.  The context of the data.

Most of this is standardized in ways that allow us to get the computer to do all the hard work ( after a programmer has done some hard work ), but without all this context it's just meaningless data.

Comment: It is my understanding that all definitions of information measure defined so far are independent of an observer's interpretation of the string carrying such information. But I might be wrong. So I am not sure how you define the "information on how to interpret the data".

Comment: If I hand you any number ( say 42 ) it has no meaning beyond that of a number until you ( or I ) supply a context.  Information measures relate to the minimum number of bits to store data, but they say nothing about the meaning attributed to that data.  There is no general way to define "information on how to interpret the data" that I know of, much less assign an information measure to it.

Comment: Thanks. Just not to add confusion to the OP, I want to make clear that this answer is based on personal opinion, not on established concepts, theories or ideas.

Comment: Is there a connection between entropy, information, and data? If entropy increases then the information, needed to describe the increased entropy, will also increase and so will the number of data.

Comment: There is a concept of [information entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)).  Strictly speaking this isn't physics ( not mainstream, anyway ) and you'd be better moving to the Computer Science forum for more.